# Creating table in React gives error - Element type is invalid

Tags: reactjs

I am creating normally table rows and columns when I am using the simple map function with the data shown below, that works just fine:

```
const tableRows = [
      {
        name: 'SickLeave difference',
        januaryPayment: '-12000',
        febrauaryPayment: '0',
      },
      {
        name: 'Holiday difference',
        januaryPayment: '10000',
        febrauaryPayment: '25000',
      },
      {
        name: 'Result',
        januaryPayment: '0',
        febrauaryPayment: '23000',
      },
    ];

    <Table headerTextCodes={headerTextCodes} allowFormattedHeader={false}>
      { tableRows.map(row => (
        <TableRow>
          <TableColumn>
            { row.name }
          </TableColumn>
          <TableColumn>
            { row.januaryPayment }
          </TableColumn>
          <TableColumn>
            { row.febrauaryPayment }
          </TableColumn>
        </TableRow>
      ))
      }
    </Table>
```

But, when I am trying to create table rows and columns where I am creating the data by first formatting the result that I am mocking currently as a backend response:

```
const result = {
      periodFrom: '2018-05-01',
      periodTo: '2018-07-31',
      sumDifference: 17873,
      periodsPerReceiver: [
        {
          receiverType: {
            code: 'ARBG_PRIV',
            name: null,
          },
          resultsPerMonth: [
            {
              from: '2018-05-01',
              to: '2018-05-31',
              resultPerField: [
                {
                  fieldCode: {
                    code: 'SP',
                    name: null,
                  },
                  previouslyPayed: 0,
                  newAmount: 2662,
                  difference: 2662,
                },
              ],
              isNewPaymentPeriod: false,
            },
            {
              from: '2018-06-01',
              to: '2018-06-30',
              resultPerField: [
                {
                  fieldCode: {
                    code: 'FP',
                    name: null,
                  },
                  paid: 6899,
                  newAmount: 0,
                  difference: -6899,
                },
              ],
              isNewPaymentPeriod: false,
            },
            {
              from: '2018-07-01',
              to: '2018-07-31',
              resultPerField: [
                {
                  fieldCode: {
                    code: 'FP',
                    name: null,
                  },
                  paid: 0,
                  newAmount: 20012,
                  difference: 20012,
                },
              ],
              isNewPaymentPeriod: false,
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          receiverType: {
            code: 'BRUKER',
            name: null,
          },
          resultsPerMonth: [
            {
              from: '2018-05-01',
              to: '2018-05-31',
              resultPerField: [
                {
                  fieldCode: {
                    code: 'FP',
                    name: null,
                  },
                  paid: 0,
                  newAmount: 0,
                  difference: 0,
                },
              ],
              isNewPaymentPeriod: false,
            },
            {
              from: '2018-06-01',
              to: '2018-06-30',
              resultPerField: [
                {
                  fieldCode: {
                    code: 'FP',
                    name: null,
                  },
                  paid: 0,
                  newAmount: 2098,
                  difference: 2098,
                },
              ],
              isNewPaymentPeriod: false,
            },
            {
              from: '2018-07-01',
              to: '2018-07-31',
              resultPerField: [
                {
                  fieldCode: {
                    code: 'FP',
                    name: null,
                  },
                  paid: 0,
                  newAmount: 0,
                  difference: 0,
                },
              ],
              isNewPaymentPeriod: false,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    };
```

I have created this function to structure data in the way I could use it to create table and table rows later in the render function:

```
const resultPerReceiver = (receiver) => {
  const receiverObject = {
    receiver: receiver.receiverType,
    fields: [],
  };

  receiver.resultsPerMonth.forEach((monthResult) => {
    monthResult.resultPerFields.forEach((resultPerField) => {
      const fieldExists = receiverObject.field.find(e => e.field.code === resultPerField.fieldCode.code);
      if (fieldExists) {
        fieldExists.rows.forEach((row) => {
          const rowExists = row.resultPerMonth.find(e => e.from === monthResult.from);
          if (!rowExists) {
            const newAmount = {
              from: monthResult.from,
              to: monthResult.to,
              amount: resultPerField.newAmount,
            };
            const paid = {
              from: monthResult.from,
              to: monthResult.to,
              amount: resultPerField.paid,
            };
            const difference = {
              from: monthResult.from,
              to: monthResult.to,
              amount: resultPerField.difference,
            };
            fieldExists.rows.find(e => e.name === 'newAmount').resultPerMonth.push(newAmount);
            fieldExists.rows.find(e => e.name === 'paid').resultPerMonth.push(paid);
            fieldExists.rows.find(e => e.name === 'difference').resultPerMonth.push(difference);
          }
        });
      } else {
        receiverObject.field.push({
          field: resultPerField.fieldCode,
          rows: [
            {
              name: 'newAmount',
              resultPerMonth: [
                {
                  from: monthResult.from,
                  to: monthResult.to,
                  amount: resultPerField.newAmount,
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              name: 'paid',
              resultPerMonth: [
                {
                  from: monthResult.from,
                  to: monthResult.to,
                  amount: resultPerField.paid,
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              name: 'difference',
              resultPerMonth: [
                {
                  from: monthResult.from,
                  to: monthResult.to,
                  amount: resultPerField.difference,
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        });
      }
    });
  });

  return receiverObject;
};

const formattedResult = result.periodsPerReceiver.map(receiver => resultPerReceiver(receiver));
```

This gives the result that looks something like this:

```
const formattedResult = [ 
  {
    receiver: {code: "ARBG_PRIV", name: null },
    fields: [
      { field: { code: "SP", name: null },
        rows: [
          {name: "newAmount", resultPerMonth: [
              {from: "2018-06-01", to: "2018-06-31", amount: 2662},
              {from: "2018-07-01", to: "2018-07-31", amount: 2662}
            ]
          },
          {name: "paid", resultPerMonth: [
              {from: "2018-06-01", to: "2018-06-31", amount: 2662},
              {from: "2018-07-01", to: "2018-07-31", amount: 2662}
            ]
          },
          {name: "difference", resultPerMonth: [
              {from: "2018-06-01", to: "2018-06-31", amount: 2662},
              {from: "2018-07-01", to: "2018-07-31", amount: 2662}
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      { field: { code: "FP", name: null },
        rows: [
          {name: "newAmount", resultPerMonth: [
              {from: "2018-06-01", to: "2018-06-31", amount: 2662},
              {from: "2018-07-01", to: "2018-07-31", amount: 2662}
            ]
          },
          {name: "paid", resultPerMonth: [
              {from: "2018-06-01", to: "2018-06-31", amount: 2662},
              {from: "2018-07-01", to: "2018-07-31", amount: 2662}
            ]
          },
          {name: "difference", resultPerMonth: [
              {from: "2018-06-01", to: "2018-06-31", amount: 2662},
              {from: "2018-07-01", to: "2018-07-31", amount: 2662}
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    receiver: {code: "BRUKER", name: null },
    fields: [
      { field: { code: "SP", name: null },
        rows: [
          {name: "newAmount", resultPerMonth: [
              {from: "2018-06-01", to: "2018-06-31", amount: 2662},
              {from: "2018-07-01", to: "2018-07-31", amount: 2662}
            ]
          },
          {name: "paid", resultPerMonth: [
              {from: "2018-06-01", to: "2018-06-31", amount: 2662},
              {from: "2018-07-01", to: "2018-07-31", amount: 2662}
            ]
          },
          {name: "difference", resultPerMonth: [
              {from: "2018-06-01", to: "2018-06-31", amount: 2662},
              {from: "2018-07-01", to: "2018-07-31", amount: 2662}
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      { field: { code: "FP", name: null },
        rows: [
          {name: "newAmount", resultPerMonth: [
              {from: "2018-06-01", to: "2018-06-31", amount: 2662},
              {from: "2018-07-01", to: "2018-07-31", amount: 2662}
            ]
          },
          {name: "paid", resultPerMonth: [
              {from: "2018-06-01", to: "2018-06-31", amount: 2662},
              {from: "2018-07-01", to: "2018-07-31", amount: 2662}
            ]
          },
          {name: "difference", resultPerMonth: [
              {from: "2018-06-01", to: "2018-06-31", amount: 2662},
              {from: "2018-07-01", to: "2018-07-31", amount: 2662}
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

Then, I am trying to render this result from the function like this in the render function:

```
<div className={styles.table}>
  {
    formattedResult.map(reciever => (
      <Table>
        { reciever.fields.map(field => field.rows.map(row => (
          <TableRow>
            <TableColumn>
              <Image
                tabIndex="0"
                className={styles.expandButton}
                src={arrowDownImageUrl}
                altCode="Timeline.openData"
              />
              { row.name }
            </TableColumn>
            { row.resultPerMonth.map(month => (
              <TableColumn>
                { month.amount }
              </TableColumn>
            ))}
          </TableRow>
        )))}
      </Table>
    ))}
</div>
```

But, when I try to do it like that, I get an error:

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
>   the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named
>   imports. in tbody (created by Table)

I have checked all the imports in the component, and I am importing them right, because this error is not happening when I am rendering the simple data shown above. I have no idea why is this happening in the latter case, what am I doing wrong?

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/38j297yn7q) you can see the sandbox for it.

Comment: Anyway, It safer to check `children && children.length ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second case, you are using `forEach` which returns `undefined`.
You should use `map` in order to get an array.

Be careful in your case, you will get an array of arrays. Maybe you should use `flatMap` from lodash or the spread operator.

Comment: I have updated the question, I have changed the function because I am creating rows with different data, and I am using nested maps, instead of forEach, but now I am getting a different error. I have also created a sandbox where it is easier to see what is the problem.

Comment: This problem is because you're returning an array of arrays : you have to flatten the result. I made a fork of your code https://codesandbox.io/s/zq2mxzlmzl. The `[].concat(...prev)` at line 38 in index.js is an equivalent of a flatten. It seems to be working for me :)

Comment: Thanks, that was it!